# Passing a column name containing spaces to filter_() inside a custom function

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, tidyverse, evaluation, tibble

can anyone show me how to get such a function working:

```
library(tidyverse)
## Testing Data:
dat  <- tibble(without_space=rep(c(0,1),5), `with space`=rep(c(1,0),5))
## Some custom function containing filter:
custom_filter  <- function(data, column, value){
    return(filter_(data, column==value))
}
## Expected Output:
filter(dat, `with space`==0)

## Function Call:
custom_filter(dat, `with space`, 0)
```

I read some stuff about Standard and Non-standard evaluation and played around with `as.name()`, `quote()` and so on, but could not get it working.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)

custom_filter  <- function(data, column, value) {

  return(filter(data, !! enquo(column) == value))

}
```